# What to do when a cache and a db index get very different?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, search-engine, google-search-api

I use memcache and datastore indexes with the google search api in gae. A practical problem is how to refresh a datastore index after an entity has been deleted since it appears that the entity is still in the index though it has been deleted. And how should I handle a more hypothetical scenario if memcache and the index start contain very different contents for the "same" data set i.e. a list of entities that can display from memcache, from the datastore index or from a datastore roundtrip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, I would recommend using the entity's key as doc_id for the index and since you have a reference to the document, you can [delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Deleting_Documents) it in a [pre_delete_hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_delete_hook). This way you can also keep the data up to date, needed since adding a new document with an existing doc_id to the index will result in overwriting the existing one. (e.g. having a post_put_hook that creates the corresponding search document)
For the second, it's probably better to make sure that you won't run into this kind of a situation than trying to remedy it by keeping them updated.